# Trying To Implement a:hover On Nav Bar with Custom Images

Tags: css, html, anchor

I'm struggling with an anchor (specifically a:hover) tag in CSS. Here's my JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yXwng/

Basically I have a nav bar with a custom image (in the fiddle I got rid of it because I'm just trying to understand the syntax and line things up). The nav bar is a div and I have five links on the nav bar which are all nested divs.

In order to make the each of the nested divs links (I made the entire div a link), I added a transparent png as the background image and set the link to the background image, thus the nav bar custom image still shows and you can click the link on the nav bar.

Now, I'm trying to make a hover/rollover image for each nav bar element. When I rollover, it shows the new image but it's aligned completely wrong (down and to the right of where the original image was). On my fiddle, I used the code, but instead of the images I'm using, I just used borders for alignment purposes. You can see on the example that the red box (which is the anchor) is not lined up for some reason with the div. That is exactly where the hover image shows up when I try to implement it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add the same dimensions to your a link, it should work perfectly:

```
#homelink a{
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: And I'd advise you to optimize your css so you don't have to repeat all properties 5 times: http://jsfiddle.net/yXwng/1/

Comment: Thanks, both suggestions are great. I'm going to work with classes now to work with the hover images as opposed to five different div ids. Much more concise, thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a display block and some line height to `<a>` like this:

```
#homelink a {
border: 1px solid red;
display: block;
line-height: 10px;
}
```

It will be aligned with div. BTW you need to use UL LI structure for it.